# How to make an animation from a bunch of plots containing subplots

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, visualization

I am playing with Non-Negative Matrix Factorisation (NMF) algorithm on MNIST database and I want to visualise how the first 15 components change when I reduce total number of components.

First I download the MNIST Database and transform it to numPy arrays

```
import numpy as np
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('./data')

images_train, labels_train = mndata.load_training()
images_test, labels_test = mndata.load_testing()

labels_train = labels_train.tolist()
labels_test = labels_test.tolist()

X_train = np.array(images_train).astype('float64')
y_train = np.array(labels_train)
X_test = np.array(images_test).astype('float64')
y_test = np.array(labels_test)
```

Then I build the NMF model with `100` components

```
from  sklearn.decomposition import NMF

nmf = NMF(n_components=100, random_state=0)
nmf.fit(X_train)
```

and I display first 15 components

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 5, figsize=(12, 7), subplot_kw={'xticks': (), 'yticks': ()})
for i, (component, ax) in enumerate(zip(nmf.components_, axes.ravel())):
    ax.imshow(component.reshape(28,28), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    ax.set_title("{}. component".format(i + 1))
```

Output:[image]

Then I repeat the same process for `50` components

Output:[image]

and lastly for `15` components

Output:[image]

I wonder if the first 15 components of these NMF models changes smoothly when I reduce the number of total components. I would like to plot whole bunch of the pictures like the ones above and display them in an animation. More precisely I would like to animate them when number of total components goes from 100 to 15 with the step equal to 5. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there anything you have done so far with respect to solving this by your own? I mean there so many questions about animations, I can't believe none of them even helps a little bit.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You got me. Having no expirience with animations, I just glanced at one tutorial and matplotlib specifications. What I have seen overwelmed me and I thought that would be easyier if someone with expirience will guide me a little. This is why I haven't done anything concerning animation. I also looked at SO questions, but after few unfit ones I decided to write this post. I see that you have a lot of expierience with matplotlib. Do you recall any SO question which might help with my problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The new day has come and with a fresh mind I figured it out. Thanks for harsh motivation.